# What is the difference between data item table and data table in data dictionary?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm creating data dictionary for the data flow it includes: data item table, data flow
table, data table (sheets), data process table.

Data item include: name of data element, meaning, type, length, range. Whereas data table (sheets) is defined by: name, type, value range, and user (?)

Can the data table (sheets) correspond to tables in the sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

Tables are database objects that contain all the data in a database. In tables, data is logically organized in a row-and-column format similar to a spreadsheet.

Each row represents a unique record, and each column represents a field in the record.

For example, a table that contains employee data for a company might contain a row for each employee and columns representing employee information such as employee number, name, address, job title, and home telephone number.

to answer your question it correspond to tables by  assigning properties to the table and to each column in the table to control the data that is allowed and other properties.

Comment: should this table include foreign keys?